# how change duplicate file name pattern in firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf

I have the same systems Ubuntu 20.04 with the newest firefox ver. on two machines. When i download the same file several times on my laptop names of downloaded files looks like: *download.pdf,download(1).pdf,downolad(2).pdf, ...* . On second Pc: *download.pdf,download-1.pdf,downolad-2.pdf, ...* . Where can I change this pattern, because I prefer second option.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the pattern Firefox uses is hard-coded without an easy way to change within the browser. This patch [Attachment #221981: Configurable file renaming during download for bug #231048](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=221981&action=diff), mentioned in this Firefox bug thread [download manager poorly renames existing files by incrementing number suffix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231048), addresses the issue by editing the source code files

- `browser/app/profile/firefox.js`
- `toolkit/mozapps/downloads/src/nsHelperAppDlg.js.in`
- `toolkit/content/contentAreaUtils.js`

However, this patch is 17 years old is never going to be included in the official build of Firefox, so it would be up to you to apply the patch to Firefox yourself. Additionally, there have been breaking changes since with this patch; the `toolkit/mozapps/downloads/src/nsHelperAppDlg.js.in` file is no longer in the latest version of Firefox. However, you can still view `toolkit/content/contentAreaUtils.js` in the latest version's source code and see how the code for adding the suffix works.
Altogether, as far as I can tell, there is no readily accessible option to change the default suffix. If you are tech-savvy enough, you could build a custom solution yourself, perhaps as a patch to the browser similar to the link above or as a plugin.