# auto-rename format

Tags: filesystem, filemanager, nautilus-script

I'm wondering if the was a way to change the format used for auto-renaming files in case the file name exists already.

The current format is:

```shell
file.txt
file (1).txt
file (2).txt
...
file (999).txt
```

I find this very ugly, the brackets make regex uglier, and the added whitespace breaks my file naming style.

I would like to change this to a much handier (for me) format something like:

```shell
file.txt
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
...
file_999.txt
```

Where the separator is configurable/arbitrary e.g. `_`, `__`, `.`, etc.

NOTE: I know I can run a script to rename them, but I'm hoping for a solution to change this behavior rather than a post-fix.

Thanks!

Comment: The behavior depends on the program that creates these files.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. I assume the downloaded files are handled by Nautilus? Not sure. I need to dig in deeper I assume.

(Ubuntu 22.04 + Gnome 42.5)

Comment: Which downloaded files? firefox, [see also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419439/how-change-duplicate-file-name-pattern-in-firefox)?